# Resource allocator in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I have this resource allocator class

```
public class ResourceAllocator {

ArrayList<Request> queue = new ArrayList<>();
Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
int maxResources;
int available;

public ResourceAllocator(int max) {
    maxResources = max;
    available = max;
}

public int getMax() {
    return maxResources;
}

public void getResources(Request req) {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        if (req.getRequest() <= available) {
            available = available - req.getRequest();
            req.allocate();
        } else {
            queue.add(req);
        }
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public void returnResources(int n) {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        available = available + n;
        if (queue.size() > 0) {
            Request req = queue.get(0);
            while (queue.size() > 0 && 
                    req.getRequest() <= available) {
                available = available - req.getRequest();
                req.allocate();
                queue.remove(0);
                if (queue.size() > 0) {
                    req = queue.get(0);
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

public int size(){
    return queue.size();
}
}
```

which is called from a thread

```
public class QThread extends Thread {

Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(0);
ResourceAllocator resources;
int number;

public QThread(ResourceAllocator rs, int n) {
    resources = rs;
    number = n;
}

public void run() {
    int items = (int) (Math.random() * resources.getMax()) + 1;
    Request req = new Request(sem, items);
    resources.getResources(req);
    try {
        sem.acquire();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
    System.out.printf("Thread %3d got %3d resources\n", number, items);
    try{
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }catch(InterruptedException ex){

    }
    resources.returnResources(items);
    System.out.printf("Thread %3d returned %3d resources\n", number,items);
}
}
```

And all is fine apart from the fact that resources are allocated FIFO.

Any ideas how could I change this to allow clients with small requests to proceed before clients with large requests, bounded overtaking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PriorityQueue` which suits best to your needs, then you can implement custom `Comparator` (if you think in future you may need a different implementation for sorting) or else `Comparable`which will sort your `Request` so that jobs in terms of size are submitted, executed first.

Answer (score 2):

how about using a PriorityQueue where the priority is the inverse of the size of the request?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size of the job ahead of time, use a [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) instead of an ArrayList to hold the jobs and implement `Comparable`
son your `Request` object such that small jobs are sorted before large ones.